# How can I use VBA to do a VLookup to compare 2 different tables and delete rows where the cell tables match?

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have an excel workbook with 3 sheets: restricted, disabled, and tickers.  Every day in column A of tickers, i will manually add a list of symbols.  I need to use VBA to do a vlookup of the contents in column A in tickers with both symbols in the restricted sheet and the disabled sheet.  if a ticker is in either the restricted or disabled list, i need VBA to delete the that row.  The list of symbols that i manually input into tickers may vary every day so I also need make the range dynamic.  The result should be a list of symbols in column b of the tickers sheet that are neither in restricted or disabled list.

Here is an example:

Restricted: AAA, BBB

Disabled: CCC, DDD

Tickers (column A): AAA, CCC, EEE, FFF, GGG

Result desired:

Tickers (column b): EEE, FFF, GGG

Comment: What did you try - any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses arrays and will be fairly quick.

```
Sub foo()
    Dim tickSht As Worksheet
    Dim restSht As Worksheet
    Dim disaSht As Worksheet
    Dim tickArr() As Variant
    Dim restArr() As Variant
    Dim disaArr() As Variant
    Dim outArr() As Variant
    Dim i&, k&, j&, r&, d&
    Dim dishr As Boolean
    Dim tichr As Boolean

    Set tickSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tickers") 'ensure that this is the correct sheet name
    Set restSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Restricted") 'ensure that this is the correct sheet name
    Set disaSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Disabled") 'ensure that this is the correct sheet name

    'load arrays
    'if you have a title row then change the "A1" to "A2" or the first row.
    'If your data is in a differect column then change the column.
    With disaSht
        disaArr = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value
    End With

    With restSht
        restArr = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value
    End With
    r = Application.Evaluate("SUM(countifs(" & tickSht.Range("A1", tickSht.Cells(tickSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Address & _
        "," & restSht.Range("A1", restSht.Cells(restSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Address & "))")
    d = Application.Evaluate("SUM(countifs(" & tickSht.Range("A1", tickSht.Cells(tickSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Address & _
        "," & disaSht.Range("A1", disaSht.Cells(disaSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Address & "))")
    With tickSht
        tickArr = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value
        ReDim outArr(1 To UBound(tickArr, 1) - d - t, 1 To 1)
        k = 1
        For i = LBound(tickArr, 1) To UBound(tickArr, 1)
            dishr = False
            tichr = False
            For j = LBound(disaArr, 1) To UBound(disaArr, 1)
                If disaArr(j, 1) = tickArr(i, 1) Then dishr = True
            Next j
            For j = LBound(restArr, 1) To UBound(restArr, 1)
                If restArr(j, 1) = tickArr(i, 1) Then tichr = True
            Next j
            If Not tichr And Not dishr Then
                outArr(k, 1) = tickArr(i, 1)
                k = k + 1
            End If
        Next i
        .Range("B1").Resize(UBound(outArr, 1), 1).Value = outArr
    End With

End Sub
```

This assumes that the data is in Column A on all three sheets and that there is no title row(s). If different then a few adjustments will be needed to be made.

This is dynamic in that it always finds the extents of the data on all three sheets loads them into arrays and iterates through those.

The use of arrays limits the number of times vba accesses the sheet in excel thus it will be quicker with larger datasets.

Comment: this worked perfectly! thank you! @scottCraner

Comment: this now returns an error that says run-time error '9': subscript out of range @scottCraner.

Comment: Which one, the first or the edit?  I added the two Application.Evaluates.